# user models in django

Tags: python, django, admin, account

I created the "Account" model but the contents on the admin dashboard and the model I created are not the same

I have manually set the fields for admin in the account section, as shown below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DySWS.png)

but what appears on the admin dashboard is like the following image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3DbF.png)

Can anyone help me to remove the fields I don't need?

Comment: please add the code for Model not images

Comment: did you run the migrations? `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: sorry I've uploaded 2 images, 1 is the admin dashboard view, and the other is the ss of my code

of course i already did

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you are inheriting AbstractUser, which looks like this:

```
class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()

    username = models.CharField(
        _("username"),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_(
            "Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only."
        ),
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={
            "unique": _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(_("first name"), max_length=150, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_("last name"), max_length=150, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _("staff status"),
        default=False,
        help_text=_("Designates whether the user can log into this admin site."),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _("active"),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            "Designates whether this user should be treated as active. "
            "Unselect this instead of deleting accounts."
        ),
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_("date joined"), default=timezone.now)
```

So if you dont need some of it's fields you can just set them as None. For example if you don't use is_staff, is_active:

```
class Account(AbstractUser):
    is_staff = None
    is_active = None
```

Comment: I did it
is_staff = None
and others too

but i am getting error "TypeError: Account() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_staff'"

Comment: Are you inheriting AbstractUser?